# Error when I try to log in to my symfony 5 project with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

very good, when I access my /login it shows me a simple FOSUserBundle login that I have commented in login_content.html.twig, instead of showing me the part of code that I edited ->

login_content.html.twig ->

```
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Login MyBar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/main_login.css') }}">
   <!-- Font Awesome 5.15.4 CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-..." crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    
    


</head>

{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.messageKey|trans(error.messageData, 'security') }}</div>
{% endif %}

{# <form action="{{ path("fos_user_security_check") }}" method="post">
    {% if csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" required="required" autocomplete="username" />

    <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" required="required" autocomplete="current-password" />

    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" />
    <label for="remember_me">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>

    <input type="submit" id="_submit" name="_submit" value="{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}" />
</form> #}
<body style="font-family: system-ui;">
<!-- Font Awesome 5.15.4 JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.4/js/all.min.js" integrity="sha512-..." crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_security_check') }}" method="post" class="login-form">
    {% if csrf_token %}
        <input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />
    {% endif %}

    <div class="login-box">
        
            <div class="login-logo">
                <img src="{{ asset('img/logovintagecolon.jpg') }}" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
            </div>
        

        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body login-card-body">
                {# <p class="login-box-msg">{{ 'security.login.welcome'|trans }}</p> #}

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">{{ 'security.login.username'|trans }}</label>
                <div class="input-group" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" class="form-control" required="required" autocomplete="username" />
                </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">{{ 'security.login.password'|trans }}</label>
                    <div class="input-group" style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;"> 
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" class="form-control" required="required" autocomplete="current-password" />
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text">
                                <button type="button" id="show-pass" style="border: none;"><i class="fas fa-eye-slash" id="togglePassword"></i></button>
                            </span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group form-check">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="remember_me" name="_remember_me" value="on" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label for="remember_me" class="form-check-label">{{ 'security.login.remember_me'|trans }}</label>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">{{ 'security.login.submit'|trans }}</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var togglePassword = document.getElementById('togglePassword');
  var passwordInput = document.getElementById('password');
  var showPass = document.getElementById('show-pass');

  showPass.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (passwordInput.type === 'password') {
      passwordInput.type = 'text';
      showPass.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye"></i>';
    } else {
      passwordInput.type = 'password';
      showPass.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-eye-slash"></i>';
    }
  });
});

</script>
</body>
```

security.yaml

```
security:
    access_denied_url: /error/403
    always_authenticate_before_granting: false
    encoders:
            FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
            ROLE_USER:        []
            ROLE_GESTOR:      []
            ROLE_CAMARERO:    []
            ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_GESTOR, ROLE_CAMARERO]
            ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_USER, ROLE_GESTOR, ROLE_CAMARERO, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
    # https://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers
    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
                id: fos_user.user_provider.username
        in_memory: { memory: ~ }
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        prod:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
              provider: fos_userbundle
              csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
              login_path: fos_user_security_login
              check_path: fos_user_security_check
            #   default_target_path: / # Ruta a la que se redirige después de iniciar sesión correctamente

            logout:       
                path: fos_user_security_logout
                target: fos_user_security_login
            anonymous:    true
```

routes.yaml ->

```
fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"

fos_user_profile:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/profile.xml"
    prefix: /profile

fos_user_register:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/registration.xml"
    prefix: /register
fos_user_resetting:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/resetting.xml"
    prefix: /resetting

fos_user_change_password:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/change_password.xml"
    prefix: /profile

profile:
    path: /profile
    controller: App\Controller\ProfileController::index

fos_user_security_logout:
    path: /logout
    methods: [GET]
access_denied_redirect:
    path: /error/403
    controller: App\Controller\ErrorController::accessDenied
```

The entire application has worked without problems on a local server (Symfony-CLI)

I installed the apache-pack to have an .htaccess inside the /public folder that did allow me to show the login on my server but without my CSS, I have enabled the apache rewrite module and it doesn't work either, I don't know what else to try...